# WCF Service error on IIS with metadata

Tags: wcf, iis

I'm trying to publish a service to IIS, it builds and runs OK on the ASP.NET dev server. When running in IIS I can get to the metadata by navigating to the service or by adding service reference in Visual Studio. But when I call a method from my client app it crashes with a internal server error. So I went to the Event Log and found this:

```
WebHost failed to process a request.
 Sender Information: System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult/8810861
 Exception: System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): There was no channel actively listening at 'http://mysite.net/soundhubservice.svc/$metadata'. This is often caused by an incorrect address URI. Ensure that the address to which the message is sent matches an address on which a service is listening. ---> System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: There was no channel actively listening at 'http://mysite.net/soundhubservice.svc/$metadata'. This is often caused by an incorrect address URI. Ensure that the address to which the message is sent matches an address on which a service is listening.
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpTransportManager.HttpContextReceived(HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.HandleRequest()
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.BeginRequest()
   at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result)
 Process Name: w3wp
 Process ID: 1080
```

My Web.Config looks something like this:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="SoundHub.Services.SoundHubService" behaviorConfiguration="StreamingServiceBehavior">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost/SoundHubServive"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint address="service" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="httpBuffering" contract="SoundHub.Services.ISoundHubService"/>
        <endpoint address="stream" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="HttpStreaming" contract="SoundHub.Services.ISoundHubStreamService"/>
        <!--<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />-->
      </service>
    </services>

    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="HttpStreaming" maxReceivedMessageSize="67108864" transferMode="Streamed"/>
        <binding name="httpBuffering" transferMode="Buffered" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="StreamingServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Tried several combinations of settings I found while searching online but nothing helped, always the same error.

Thanks
Bruno

Comment: Get the same error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5778774/wcf-3-5-svc-service-webhost-failed-to-process-a-request

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when one of the objects I returned contained an enumeration; turns out it couldn't figure out how to serialize it.

If that's your problem, try returning the int value of the enum (or a string value) and cast it back to the enum on the client side.